# Python "SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/docutils/"

Tags: python, ssl, pip, homebrew, django

**PROBLEM**

- Whatever I try to install from terminal with pip (macOS 10.12) I get this error message
- I may have installed and fully deleted **homebrew** before but I am not sure how to solve this

**Installs I try to run** (all cases same error message)

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install django-storages
pip install ssl
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django-storages/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django-storages/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-storages (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-storages
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

**Tried Solutions**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59280089/10270590
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742171/pip-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-problem
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in/59280089#59280089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29969862/10270590

go to your virtualenv directory (but don't run workon):

```
cd ~/.virtualenv/name_of_broken_venv
```

Now delete these files:

```
rm -rf .Python bin/python* lib/python2.7/* include/python2.7
```

Then to rebuild your venv, run:

```
virtualenv .
pip install -r requirements.txt
```